# Automatically highlight words from a predefined list

Tags: highlighting, automation

I am not a native English speaker and there are some grammar mistakes I do a lot, especially *have/has* in conjunction with *each/every*, and so on.

Q: **Is there some way to highlight all occurrences of some words (from a list I specify) in a document automatically?**

Comment: The new question at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/242279/7883 is perhaps relevant.

Comment: Yes, it is similar; however, all solutions presented there require extra software or that one manually mark all instances where one wants to do some highlightning

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [listings package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) to do this, although it is not ideal because the text won't be typeset "normally" and most comments are disabled inside a `lstlisting` environment. If you are happy with these constraints then this might be OK, at least for drafts.

Here's what is does to your question:

[image]

and here is the latex code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{morekeywords={have,has,each,every},  % define the words to be highlighted
        keywordstyle=\color{blue},           % define how they are highlighted
}


\begin{document}
  \begin{lstlisting}% wrap your text inside a listings environment
    I am not a native English speaker and there are some grammar mistakes
    I do a lot, especially have/has in conjunction with each/every, and so
    on.

    Q: Is there some way to highlight all occurrences of some words (from
    a list I specify) in a document automatically?
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

With `luatex`, you can use the package `chickenize`, somewhat like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chickenize}
\addtosubstitutions{have}{HAVE}
\addtosubstitutions{has}{HAS}
\addtosubstitutions{each}{EACH}
\addtosubstitutions{every}{EVERY}
\begin{document}
\substitutewords
I am not a native English speaker and there are some grammar mistakes
I do a lot, especially have/has in conjunction with each/every, and so
on.

Is there some way to highlight all occurrences of some words (from a
list I specify) in a document automatically?
\end{document}
```

Once you’ve checked all occurrences of the problematic words, simply comment out `\substitutewords`, and they’ll go back to being lowercase instead of all caps.